Group_by, change words from a column with a condition
Not at ease with R, I face the following problem:
I have a table with, among others, species' name, Event ID where all records of a same event are named under the same ID (according to time), and the behaviours displayed on each record, like the following:



Event ID
Species
Behaviour




E0001
fox
Pass


E0002
Cat
Pass


E0002
Cat
Rest


E0002
Cat
Pass


E0003
Hare
Forage


E0003
Hare
Pass


E0004
fox
Forage


E0004
fox
Forage


E0004
fox
Rest



The problem is that, when I get rid of the duplicated events, I also get rid of some behaviours (example, the Cat is only passing, and "Rest" is deleted).
What I would like to do is the following:
For each event, if there is 1 behaviour different from "Pass", then keep the different(s) behaviour(s).
The result should be:



Event_ID
Behaviour




E0001
Pass


E0002
Rest


E0003
Forage


E0004
Forage, Rest



I have tried to do so with group_by and sumarise or mutate, but I couldn't get anything satisfactory or without making errors...
The best I could get was:
event_bhv <- data %>% group_by(Event_ID) %>%
  summarise(event_behaviour = max(Behaviour))

Which only provides me the behaviour that occurs the most (so, if there are 3 pass and 1 forage, I get pass, which is not my aim).
If anyone has a solution, that would help me very much.

I think the key is to find a way to filter out the "Pass" records that are not of interest, which is !(n() > 1 & Behaviour == "Pass").
library(dplyr)

df |> 
  group_by(EventID) |> 
  filter(!(n() > 1 & Behaviour == "Pass")) |> 
  summarize(Behaviour = paste(unique(Behaviour), collapse = ", ")) |> 
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 4 × 2
  EventID Behaviour   
  <chr>   <chr>       
1 E0001   Pass        
2 E0002   Rest        
3 E0003   Forage      
4 E0004   Forage, Rest


It works perfectly. Thank you so much!

Base R solution:
aggregate(
  Behaviour~EventId+Species,
  FUN = function(x){
    paste0(unique(x), collapse = ",")
  },
  data = df[df$Behaviour != "Pass",]
) |>  rbind(
  unique(
    df[
        with(
        df,
        ave(EventId, EventId, FUN = length) == as.integer(
          with(
            df,
            ave(
              Behaviour, 
              EventId, 
              FUN = function(x){
                sum(as.character(x) == "Pass")
              }
            )
          )
        )
      ),
    ]
  )
) |>
  (\(x) x[order(x[,"EventId"]), ])()

Input Data:
df <- structure(
  list(
    EventId = c(
      "E0001",
      "E0002",
      "E0002",
      "E0002",
      "E0003",
      "E0003",
      "E0004",
      "E0004",
      "E0004"
    ),
    Species = c(
      "fox",
      "Cat", 
      "Cat", 
      "Cat", 
      "Hare", 
      "Hare", 
      "fox", 
      "fox", 
      "fox"
    ),
    Behaviour = c(
      "Pass",
      "Pass",
      "Rest",
      "Pass",
      "Forage",
      "Pass",
      "Forage",
      "Forage",
      "Rest"
    )
  ),
  class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA,-9L)
)

